# Windows Mobile 'OK' button

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I've discovered *how* to disable the "OK" button in my Windows Mobile application (by setting `ControlBox` to *false*).

The problem I had was that it was possible for me to close my application by pressing this "OK" button, but the FormClosing, FormClosed events were not fired, and most worrying, the form's Dispose() method was not called either. This made it quite difficult to clean up things like threads and other resources.

Now that I can force the user to use my own "Quit" button, those methods all get executed as I would expect.

**Question**: why does the "OK" button in a Windows Mobile application close the application while bypassing the methods I mentioned?

Comment: Did you mean the 'OK' button or the 'X', IIRC when you hit the 'X' button your app doesn't close, it's just hidden, so when the user runs it again it's just brought back to the top. I think the 'OK' button was shown only for dialog windows.

Comment: IIRC the <-- button actually closes the app or the current window of the app.

Comment: It's the "OK" button. My application is *not* modal.

Comment: Because this question comes up when trying to figure out how to get rid of the ok button I want to say that by setting the controlbox property to false you can get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote the code for the `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` events, did you remember to wire the actual form up to use these?

I have a few Windows Mobile applications that I maintain, and they call the methods I created for them.

I often forget to set the Controls to use the code that I write for them, so that was the first thing I thought of.

**EDIT:** I do not use Microsoft's `OK` button, but instead make use of a Menu that has an EXIT Menu Item.

[image: Wm5 in GUI]

I also turn off the Soft Input Panel (SIP) and Task Bar by P/Invoking the "coredll" file in the `Program.cs` file before my main program executes.

That may be a solution for you. If so, this should be all of the code I use for that. Be sure to test it, and if something is missing, let me know and I'll update it.

```
const string COREDLL = "coredll.dll";

[DllImport(COREDLL, EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport(COREDLL, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

private static Form1 objForm = null;
private static IntPtr _taskBar = IntPtr.Zero;
private static IntPtr _sipButton = IntPtr.Zero;

[MTAThread]
static void Main() {
  ShowWindowsMenu(false);
  try {
    objForm = new Form1();
    Application.Run(objForm);
  } catch (Exception err) {
    objForm.DisableTimer();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(err.Message)) {
      ErrorWrapper("AcpWM5 Form (Program)", err);
    }
  } finally {
    ShowWindowsMenu(true); // turns the menu back on
  }
}

private static void ShowWindowsMenu(bool enable) {
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) {
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _taskBar = FindWindowCE("HHTaskBar", null); // Find the handle to the Start Bar
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show Start" : "Hide Start", err);
  }
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _sipButton = FindWindowCE("MS_SIPBUTTON", "MS_SIPBUTTON");
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show SIP" : "Hide SIP", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the events are hooked up. They are executed properly when I close the form using Close().

Comment: So it is Microsoft's little OK button that is not firing anything that Windows Mobile is able to pass along. I made some changes that might get you "unstuck".

Comment: It's not a problem anymore, now that I've hidden the OK button setting `ControlBox = false`. My question was more related to what's happening that would cause this behaviour. To me, it seems like a major UI blunder to allow the user to seemingly close the program without actually closing it. Matt's comment above seems like it might be a good answer - OK just hides the window. Having never used this platform before, and seeing the OK button in the same spot I'd expect an X button - you can see where my confusion arose.

Comment: (ok) closes the Form, (X) minimizes it. Which is shown depends on the ShowMinimizeButton property of the Form.  If you remove the control box completely you can only transfer focus (short of wiring your own button or menu that calls Close on the Form instance itself).

Comment: @CharlieSalts: That is by design. All of the programs are actually installed into RAM, since there is no hard drive. Therefore, it was decided (I believe) that there was no benefit to closing an application rather than simply minimizing it. As the battery dies, apps on the mobile device are supposed to respond to the low battery notice and save their data.